# jQuery Cycle - img slide not loaded, requeuing slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug, jquery-cycle

I'm using jQuery Cycle plugin to create a very simple slideshow:

Markup:

```
<div class="gallery group">

    <div class="slide-nav">
        <a href="#" class="previous">&laquo; Ver anterior</a>
        <a href="#" class="view">Ver Ficha</a>
        <a href="#" class="next">Ver siguiente &raquo;</a>
    </div><!-- /slide-nav -->

    <div class="slider">

        <div class="slides">
            <img src="img/gallery01.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="img/gallery02.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="img/gallery01.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="img/gallery02.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>

        <div class="thumbs"></div>

    </div><!-- /slider -->

</div><!-- /gallery -->
```

Script:

```
jQuery('.gallery .slider .slides').cycle({ 
    fx:     'fade', 
    speed:  '800', 
    timeout: 3000, 
    prev:   '.gallery .slide-nav a.previous',
    next:   '.gallery .slide-nav a.next',
    pager:  '.gallery .slider .thumbs',

    // callback fn that creates a thumbnail to use as pager anchor 
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
        var img = jQuery(slide).find("img").attr("src");
        return '<a href="#"><img src="' + img + '" /></a>';
    } 
});
```

`pagerAnchorBuilder` is function that creates thumbnails in the `pager` (`.thumbs` in my example). The idea is that thumbnails are created in `.thumbs` and `.slides` is the wrapper for slides (images in my case).

However, I'm getting this in log in the console (not error or warning, just log):

> [cycle] 1  - img slide not loaded,
>   requeuing slideshow: gallery01.jpg 0 0

The slideshow still works, but it doesn't create the thumbnails, telling me the `img` variable from the `pagerAnchorBuilder` function is undefined.

Any idea what the "requeuing slideshow" mean and why the image is undefined? I used this exact snippet many many times in the past, and never had this problem before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm ...

```
    var img = jQuery(slide).find("img").attr("src");
```

If the "slide" passed in to your "pagerAnchorBuilder" callback will be one of the `<img>` elements in the "slides" `<div>`, then you don't need the "find()".  It should be just:

```
    var img = jQuery(slide).attr('src');
```

or, simpler:

```
    var img = slide.src;
```

The ".find()" method won't ever include the starting element; it only looks at descendants in the DOM.

Comment: Oops! Of course! I guess I need some caffeine... Thanks a lot!